# How to upload odt/doc/pdf/txt files with php

Tags: php, file-upload

I can't get my uploadscript to work for the fileformates pdf, doc, odt and txt.
Is there a way to accept all fileformates, just with limmited maxsize on the object?
Here is my script:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "doc", "odt", "pdf", "txt");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/txt")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/doc")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/odt"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Feilmelding: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Denne filen er lastet opp: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type fil:: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Størrelse: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " Filen eksisterer, bytt navn. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Filen er lagret her: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Feil Filtype";
  }
?>
```

It works for the pictures, but not the applications.
Any help would be most appreciated, have a great eve

In advance, thank you :)

Comment: Have a look at the different [MIME Types](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list).

Comment: I would print or otherwise log the $_FILES["file"]["type"] string above your if() {} statement to make sure the MIME type coming through (and parsed by php) is the MIME type you expect.  As Jason points out above, .odt might very well come through with "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" for the mime type.

Comment: Don't use the w3fools upload script. It's very bad code and highly insecure.

Comment: What in particular is not working? How far does it get within your if/else structure? Does it go to echo "Feil Filtype", or does it fail somewhere within the if?

Comment: It works now that I figured out the MIME-types, thanks a bunch :)
It's just for a little group-chat-application, so security ain't much of a priority, as it probably should, but thanks for the remark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use incorrect media types. The correct media-types are:

- application/msword for .doc
- text/plain for .txt
- application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text for .odt
- application/pdf for .pdf